# How are PHP objects attached to a user in a web app

Tags: php, session, object

My question is if a user comes along and uses an Object Oriented PHP application, how are those objects tied to the user and what happens to them once the user leaves?

I understand how OO

Comment: I think that some part of your question has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a [shared-nothing architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture), which means that for every HTTP request the browser makes, the application starts with an empty sheet (so far as PHP internals such as variables and loaded classes are concerned). Every PHP object disappears at the end of the request. Permanent data needs to be stored elsewhere (typically a database plus possibly a key-value based cache such as memcached). How user-related data is handled in those outside storages depends entirely on the application.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are not really ever tied to a user... It sounds like you are talking about sessions variables. You can store some information for an individual user by adding it to the php `$_SESSION` variable like this for example: `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 5`. Once the user leaves, that information will still be accessible until it expires (You can set the expiration date, or typically it will expire when the user closes their browser). For most web applications dealing with users, the user will be asked to log in and when they do, information about that user gets stored in the session. This allows a user to stay signed in across multiple pages of the pages application. Then if the user decides to log out, this is when you unset or destroy that session data.

Answer (score 0):

When an HTTP request is received, PHP is fired up, sets up the runtime environment for your code and runs it. Afterwards all of this is torn down, to be re-created from scratch on the next request.

So unless you take explicit steps to persist your objects (or any other type of variable, really) to e.g. disk and then read them back on a subsequent request, there will be no trace of objects created in the past at all.